# Export_to_png only saves background

Tags: python, kivy

I recently learnt about the Python framework kivy and started to follow [the simple paint app tutorial](https://kivy.org/docs/tutorials/firstwidget.html). Now I want to save what was drawn as a .png file but instead of the colored dots it only exports the black background.

This is my code example:

```
import kivy
kivy.require("1.9.1")

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Line

class MyPaintWidget(Widget):
    def on_touch_down(self,touch):
        color=(0,0,1)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(*color)
            d=30.
            Ellipse(pos=(touch.x-d/2., touch.y-d/2.), size=(d,d))

class MyPaintApp(App):

    def build(self):
        parent=Widget()
        self.painter=MyPaintWidget()
        ssbtn=Button(text='Save')
        ssbtn.bind(on_release=self.save_screenshot)
        parent.add_widget(self.painter)
        parent.add_widget(ssbtn)
        return parent

    def save_screenshot(self,obj):
        self.painter.export_to_png("screenshot.png")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyPaintApp().run()
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: the best way to figure out what's wrong is by using: https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.modules.inspector.html#module-kivy.modules.inspector, you can activate it as it's stated here: https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.modules.html#activating-a-module, by adding `inspector =` to the `config.ini` file under `[modules]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing one thing - `Widget` won't set its size and position automatically to whole `Window` size, but only to default ones i.e. `pos = [0, 0]` `size = [100, 100]` because `Window != Layout` and even adding it to something that doesn't inherit from a `Layout` won't make it better (`Widget != Layout`) which you can easily see if you look a that saved png (is too small).

```
self.painter=MyPaintWidget(size=[800,600])
```

will make the job for you if you plan to stay only on pc and only with the default `Window` size. If not, then use:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
self.painter=MyPaintWidget(size=Window.size)
```

which seems to be more practical, yet you're still not there. An optimal solution would be using a `Layout` which does these things for you such as `BoxLayout`, `GridLayout` or [some others](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.layout.html).

And a perfect solution for you would be to use a [`StencilView`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.stencilview.html)in a `Layout`, which when is placed won't take a screenshot of the whole canvas, but only the part you'd think it'll take i.e. the part sized as the `Widget` itself placed on its position.

Try drawing outside of the red box. Inspector will provide you with showing widgets in a color and other functions, so definitely try it as it was mentioned in the comments.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.stencilview import StencilView
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Line, Rectangle

class MyPaintWidget(StencilView):
    def on_touch_down(self,touch):
        color=(0,0,1)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(*color)
            d=30.
            Ellipse(pos=(touch.x-d/2., touch.y-d/2.), size=(d,d))

class MyPaintApp(App):
    def build(self):
        parent=Widget()
        self.painter=MyPaintWidget(size=[i/2.0 for i in Window.size])
        with self.painter.canvas:
            Color(1, 0, 0, 0.3)
            Rectangle(pos=self.painter.pos, size=self.painter.size)
        ssbtn=Button(text='Save')
        ssbtn.bind(on_release=self.save_screenshot)
        parent.add_widget(self.painter)
        parent.add_widget(ssbtn)
        return parent

    def save_screenshot(self,obj):
        self.painter.export_to_png("screenshot.png")
MyPaintApp().run()
```